# At what voltage are "low voltage" junction boxes not appropriate?

Tags: junction-box, low-voltage

120VAC needs a proper, enclosed junction box. Speaker cable, data, and low voltage power are fine with the more open low-voltage boxes. At what voltage are the enclosed boxes required? Do PoE lines (48VDC) need the same boxes as 120VAC? What's the cut-off?

Comment: Typically communication wiring is allowed to use "low voltage" boxes, and power wiring must use closed boxes.  [Power over Ethernet (PoE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) combines both, but I suspect would fall back to the safetiest which would be closed boxes.

Comment: If I remember correctly POE was designed to fall under low voltage most places so existing data wiring could be used.  I have never seen ethernet cables used for PoE put inside an enclosed box.

Answer (score 1):

Regulations vary by country/locale.

IEC [SELV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage) is < 25 VAC or < 60 VDC.

See [IEEE 802.3 POEP Study Group
Safety considerations for POE and POEplus](http://www.ieee802.org/3/poep_study/public/mar05/peker_1_0305.pdf)

Comment: What locale are you reporting about?

Comment: @bib: Ones that, directly or indirectly, base regulations on IEC/IEEE definitions. :-)